# PPFD vs general sunlight requirements

Tags: sunlight, light

Can someone give (or point me to) a rough guide of the correlation between generalized sunlight requirements (i.e. partial sun, indirect sunlight, full sun, etc...) and their approximate corresponding PPFD (Photosynthetic Photon Flux Density) values?

I ask because it is difficult for me to parse these generalized values given that I am in a semi-tropical environment, US Hardiness Zone 9b.

Specifically, Peace Lily care requirements state that they do well in low light, but 'low' is a highly relative term, and a more precise suggested (even approximate) PPFD value would be much more helpful. I am trying to determine whether I should get a brighter L.E.D. for the Peace Lily I am growing inside.

Comment: Is this question possibly more appropriate for the biology exchange or some other exchange? If so, leave a comment, and I will delete the question here and repost in a different exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Peace Lily [Spathiphyllum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum) based on [Purdue University's Extension](https://www.extension.purdue.edu/extmedia/HO/HO-238-W.pdf) can be grown between 2 to 10 Daily Light Integrals for that day.  Taking that into account you can briefly determine what PPFD the Peace Lily can get.  Try this [calculator](https://www.waveformlighting.com/horticulture/daily-light-integral-dli-calculator).
If you can get the specs for your LED you could try your hand with this [calculator](http://dev.edman007.com/~edman007/pub/par-dli-cal.html) to determine correct height and light output to generate the corresponding DLI and PPFD.